# Java StringTokenizer - Problems with nextToken() usage with substring

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I have a text file I must iterate through and want to move certain elements of each line into an `ArrayList`. Each line of the file is in the format: number. String number. decimal decimal
As the two numbers have a full stop (.) at the end and I need to read these as a String, removed the . using substring and then convert to a primitive data type (`int` or `short`).

Example on file:
294.    ABC123  66. .00 .00

I get a string range error if I try this:  (* temp is a String)

```
while(fileLine.hasMoreTokens())
{
    oneNumber = Integer.valueOf(fileLine.nextToken().substring(0, 
                          fileLine.nextToken().indexOf('.')));
    twoString = fileLine.nextToken();
    threeNumber = Short.valueOf(fileLine.nextToken().substring(0, 
                          fileLine.nextToken().indexOf('.')));
    temp = fileLine.nextToken();    //Handle attributes not required
    temp = fileLine.nextToken();    //Handle attributes not required
}
```

I believe why this is happening is that the nextToken() in the substring's parameters is confusing the StringTokenizer. So I fixed it like this:

```
                while(fileLine.hasMoreTokens())
                {
                    temp = fileLine.nextToken();
                    oneNumber = Integer.valueOf(temp.substring(0, temp.indexOf('.')));
                    twoString = fileLine.nextToken();
                    temp = fileLine.nextToken();
                    threeNumber= Short.valueOf(temp.substring(0, temp.indexOf('.')));
                    temp = fileLine.nextToken();
                    temp = fileLine.nextToken();
                }
```

While this works it feels a bit redundant. Is there something I can try to make this cleaner, while retaining use of the `StringTokenizer`?

Comment: That doesn't seem redundant to me. Its the way your input is. But if your input format is fixed  a regex would be a better choice, you just apply regex and you will get the parts in much cleaner way.

Comment: I would not use the name `temp` which is a terrible variable name and should only be used for e.g., temp files. Also, `StringTokenizer` is a very old class and is generally not recommended for use in new code.

Answer (score 1):

This is the intended behavior of `.nextToken()`: it returns the token and moves past the current token. When you use `Integer.valueOf(fileLine.nextToken().substring(0, fileLine.nextToken().indexOf('.')))`, you are calling `.nextToken()` twice, which means you are dealing with two distinct tokens. It has nothing to do with how `String#substring` works. You need to store the token in a variable if you need to perform additional operations on it. This exact same problem can also be caused by using `BufferedReader#readLine` twice when one should be storing the value.

Answer (score 1):

Yup. `nextToken()` is stateful, calling it changes things, so using it twice in a single line would consume two tokens.

Your second snippet seems much easier to read to me, so I'm not sure what the problem is. Presumably you want your code to be more readable.

An easy fix is to make helper methods:

```
while (fileLine.hasMoreTokens()) {
    oneNumber = fetchHeadingNumber(fileLine);
    twoString = fileLine.nextToken();
    threeNumber = fetchHeadingNumber(fileLine);
    fileLine.nextToken(); // no need to assign it.
    fileLine.nextToken();
}
```

with this method:

```
int fetchHeadingNumber(StringTokenizer t) {
    String token = t.nextToken();
    return Integer.parseInt(token.substring(0, token.indexOf('.')));
}
```

you can go even further and make a class representing a line, which has all the code needed to parse it (I made up names; your snippet doesn't make clear what kind of thing the line represents):

```
@lombok.Value class InventoryItem {
    int warehouse;
    String name;
    int shelf;

    public static InventoryItem read(StringTokenizer tokenizer) {
        int warehouse = num(tokenizer);
        String name = tokenizer.nextToken();
        int shelf = num(tokenizer);
        tokenizer.nextToken();
        tokenizer.nextToken();
        return new InventoryItem(warehouse, name, shelf);
    }
    private static int num(StringTokenizer t) {
        String token = t.nextToken();
        return Integer.parseInt(token.substring(0, token.indexOf('.')));
    }
}
```

and then reading a line and retrieving, say, the location where it is stored is so much nicer: Now things actually have names!

```
InventoryItem item = InventoryItem.read(fileLine);
System.out.println("This item is in warehouse " + item.getWarehouse());
```

NB: Uses [lombok's @Value](https://projectlombok.org/features/Value) to avoid putting a lot of boilerplate in this answer.

Comment: Thanks all for the insights, appreciated!